# How to incorporate href into google visualization library javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using Google's Visualization library to draw a chart in my Rails app.  My code right now is:

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Phrase', 'Frequency'],
        <% @frequency.each do |key,value| %>
            ['<%= key %>', <%= value %>],
        <% end %>
    ]);
```

This works.  However, I want to enable a feature that allows a user to click on the value on the y axis which then fires an event (opens a link, for example).  I tried the code below but it doesn't work.  Any advice on how I can incorporate a href into the js snippet above?

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Phrase', 'Frequency'],
        <% @frequency.each do |key,value| %>
            [<a href = "#"'<%= key %>'</a>, <%= value %>],
        <% end %>
    ]);
```

I'm also open to including a href in the tooltip that display on the chart.

Link to the API is: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

### HTML ToolTips

The first is to use [html tooltips](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#enabling_html_tooltip) to make the URL display when you mouseover the bar.

This is the easiest way, but it is your second choice.

### Custom Event Handler

To make something happen when you click a chart item, you will need to create a custom event handler.

First look at the documentation for [events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Events) on a bar chart. In this case, you will need to use a `select` event.

When the `select` event is called, you can use the `getSelection()` function to see which row of data is being selected. If you have the URL you want to use in the third column, you can just use `data.getValue()` for the selected row, and use javascript to open the link as desired.

You can configure it however you'd like, but this should set you on the proper path to be able to figure it out.